# highstock chart only set the max value of xAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to only set the max value of xAxis. I get this value from session value.
I want to display stockchart. The selected range of xAxis is set(from session value) and not changing. How to link the max xAxis value to the rangeSelectorButton and input range selector or and navigator. Click range button or input range or navigator, the max value of xAxis doesn't change.

If i use the following code, I have to sent the value of both min and max value.

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      SetExtremes: function (e) {
        if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton") {
          setTimeout(function () {
            var end = 1293091200000;
            Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(1198681756385, end)
          }, 1);

        }
      },
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

How can I only set the max value?
The reason why I want this, because I get a date from session value, then I can choose different button range selector to show past week or past 1 month or past 3 month chart.

Comment: You said you want to set the max value of the axis but your code is trying to set the max extreme (the selected range on the navigator) of x-axis. Which one do exactly want?

Comment: I want to only set the max extreme (the selected range on the navigator or range button) of x-axis.

Comment: without changing the min extreme?

Comment: yeah, don't set the min extreme. The max value is set so with different range button, it can set the time range as past week or past month or past half year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `setExtremes`, not `SetExtremes`.

Second thing, calling `setExtremes` in `setExtremes` callback makes infinite loop.

I advice to disable `rangeSelector` from Highcharts, generate your own HTML buttons, and add click event where you will call `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(previous_min, your_max_value);`.

Comment: how to setExtremes for inputrange, so it can choose different start time but end time is fixed. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean inputs built-in Highstock? They are always enabled or disabled. You can't disable editing for one of them directly. Only some hacky way. I guess, generating your own inputs would be again faster and give you more control.

Comment: generating your own inputs means pass an input as starttime to the chart?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about, honestly :) I asked you - do you mean built-in inputs? Like this: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputEnabled

Comment: if set inputenable to false, both the input range box will not display.

Comment: Let me asnwer again the same: They are always enabled or disabled. You can't disable editing for one of them directly. Only some hacky way(editing sources). I guess, creating your own inputs would be again faster and give you more control.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to set the max value of the extreme (selected range on navigator) without changing the min extreme, you can first retrieve the current extreme and set the same value back:

```
// Assume the chart instance is stored in variable 'chart'
var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.min, yourMaxValue);
```

Comment: hi, I tried your method. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jennysayhello/D8bem/). The problem is that when i choose 1 month, 3 month, 6 month, it cannot calculate the right beginning date. When I choose the YTD, it can give right beginning date as Jan 1st. But if i choose 1 month button after choose YTD, the webpage will have to reload.

Comment: @programbegin Sorry but I'm confused by your code. Can you describe what you are trying to do? It seems you want the max value to be fixed, while you also don't want the min value to change. Then what should happen when user clicks a range selector button, say, `1m`?

Comment: I want the max value to be fixed and min value change with different selected range button. If the max value is 2012-5-20. then you select 1m, it should display the chart from 2012-4-20 to 2012-5-20

Comment: @programbegin Then the chart looks good to me without adding any code to setExtremes. The only problem is button `YTD` and `All` but they can easily be removed. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y89eP/). Is this what you want?

Comment: The start time is wrong. The max value now is 2012-12-03 and I choose 1 month then it shows the start time is 2012-11-02. It should be 2012-11-03. Also it display the chart from 2012-11-05.